# ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync is not working in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform, unityscript

I am using Unity Facebook SDK for facebook login in my Unity project. After login gets successful I am trying to use logInSync through ParseFacebookUtils. I am not getting any data in Parse cloud browser.

I got all the parameters like accessToken, userId, tokenExpiration from Facebook SDK and this is the I tried in unityscript. When i tried this on my Android device

```
var logInTask:Task = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(accessToken, userId, tokenExpiration);
```

There is no error but nothing happened in cloud browser data as well. Now I thought this might be because I removed "ParseUser" from Task.
So I tried to put ParseUser in the code and used this code

```
var logInTask:Task<ParseUser> = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(accessToken, userId, tokenExpiration);
```

I get these errors in unity editor log

> Unexpected token: <
>
> ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end
>
> Unexpected token: >
>
> ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end

Simple SaveAsync is working for me like

```
var testTask:Task = testObject.SaveAsync();
```

And my data gets saved in cloud browser data.

*Someone help me out with Facebook Login and Signup in Parse.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have to change the order for your parameters.
Got this reply from Parse guys to solve this problem

"You just need to fix the order of your parameters using something like this:"

```
ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, DateTime.Now);
```

Original link to the answer:

https://www.parse.com/questions/parsefacebookutilsloginasync-is-not-working-in-unity3d#answer-you-just-need-to-fix-the-order-of-your-parameters